# android setTypeface

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple main class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    databaseHelper = new wecDatabasesManager(this); 
    databaseHelper.open(); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    series = databaseHelper.getSeries();

    startManagingCursor(series);

    setListAdapter(new SeriesListAdapter(this, series));

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

I also have a simple adapter

```
public class SeriesListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    public SeriesListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context,R.layout.series_row, c, 
      new String[] { wecSeriesTable.NAME }, 
          new int[] {R.id.series_name});
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {    
      super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
      String SerieName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(wecSeriesTable.NAME));
    }
}
```

Now my question:
How can i change the fontface?

i have found this code

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "whatelsecomicsfont.ttf");
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.series_name);
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

i had pasted it into getView method in my main class but it don't work
Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a font called whatelsecomicsfont.ttf in your assets folder? Android SDK only comes with a couple of fonts, the code you are using is for custom fonts.

Comment: put the ttf in assets/ not in assets/fonts/ or change the string passed in createFromAsset

Comment: yes, i have a custom font in my assets folder. What i nedd to use that font?

Comment: Is it showing any error?

Answer (score -1):

Change the font file (*.ttf file)